# Find out where length semantics gets changed

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, sqlplus, oracle-sql-developer, oracle-xe

I've code to create tables that doesn't specify length semantics:

```
CREATE TABLE CHAR_TEST (
    CHAR_TEST_ID NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL,
    FOO VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,
    BAR VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT CHAR_TEST_PK PRIMARY KEY (CHAR_TEST_ID) ENABLE
);
```

Actual code is fairly large and contains hundreds of objects. I have two versions of the code that correspond to different source control revisions separated by a couple of years.

I've created 2 users/schemas on the same server with identical settings. I then run each revision in each respective schema. To my surprise, the latest revision gets an unexpected `CHAR` semantic:

```
Name         Null     Type        
------------ -------- ----------- 
CHAR_TEST_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(38)  
FOO          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6) 
BAR          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)
```

```
Name         Null     Type        
------------ -------- ---------------- 
CHAR_TEST_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(38)  
FOO          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6 CHAR) 
BAR          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6 CHAR)
```

I can't figure out where those `CHAR` come from!

- I can't reproduce it if I run `CREATE TABLE` code isolately
- I've been unable to find `ALTER TABLE CHAR_TEST` statements in my code base that change anything but keys or indexes
- `SELECT value FROM V$PARAMETER WHERE NAME LIKE '%nls_length_semantics%';` prints `BYTE` in both schemas

Could you please suggest where to look further?

Comment: I always use `select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS'` - does that show a different value than the one stored in `v$parameter`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's `BYTE` anyway. But I think I'm just a plain idiot... Please let me check something and I'll report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot the most obvious thing: session parameters can be changed!

I had this on the latest revision:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = 'CHAR';
```

... but not the older one. I was running the scripts in a different session thus I couldn't spot the value change.